# Why implement stacks and queues java

Tags: java, stack

Why should you implement a stack or queue when the same function can be achived with a list?

Comment: Even if you are the only developer, you can forget the assumptions you make when you write the code originally.  The more functionality you expose the more likely you will have a bug/misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stack and queue may be based on list, but they have a specific behavior. It requires less implementation on your side, and gives you a more concrete and clarified behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Why allow direct access to all elements in your collection when you only want/need to allow access to the front or tail element?

Additionally, `stack.pop()` is easier to understand than `list.remove(list.size()-1)`, and the same applies to most of the other stack and queue operations.

Comment: and… `list.remove(list.size()-1)` isn't even thread-safe; it would require external synchronization, or size could change before the remove(). On the other hand, a pop() method can synchronize the operations to guarantee the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2):

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack/

Above link will explain you the clear picture why they have introduced

These new structures have introduced just keep faster performance in mind and Instead of rewriting the classes again...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when implementing a more specific data structure with more specific purpose, better efficiency can be achieved both in data structure implementation and in the usage API.